# ¿Por qué mi sidebar no va hasta el fondo del sitio?

Tags: html, css

Quiero que mi sidebar tenga un height del 100% pero se queda por la mitad de la pagina, porque sera?

Sidebar CSS

```
nav.sidebar{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -160px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Content CSS

```css
.content{
     padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
     float: center;
}
```

HTML

```html
<LateralMenu />
<div className="content">
<center>
<div className="c--anim-btn">
  <span className="c-anim-btn">
    <div className="logo-home" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: xxxxlogo }}/>
  </span>
  <span>
     xxxxx
  </span>
</div>
<hr width="50%"/>
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
</center>
</div>
```

Sidebar HTML

```html
<nav className="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span claclassNamess="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>      
    </div>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        <li className="hvr-wobble-horizontal"><a href="/">Home<span style={style} className="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li className="hvr-wobble-horizontal"><a href="/demos">Demos<span style={style} className="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span></a></li>
        <li className="hvr-wobble-horizontal"><a href="/categories">Categories<span style={style} className="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>   
        <li className="hvr-wobble-horizontal"><a href="/users">Users<span style={style} className="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>                
        <li className="hvr-wobble-horizontal"><a href="/logout">Logout<span style={style} className="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</nav>
```

PD: Estoy usando ReactJS por eso el `<lateralmenu / >` pero es como si fuera un simple `<div>` con el sidebar

Comment: Coloca el HTML del sidebar también. ¿Quieres que la parte donde va el contenido sea scrollable?

Comment: Ahi lo agregue, quiero que digamos el largo de el menu abarque toda la pagina osea que llegue hasta el bottom.

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar el `HTML` resultante en lugar de cada parte por separado?

Comment: Santiago, ¿tu aplicación tiene el diseño de un dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que un elemento coja el 100% de la altura del contenedor, ese contenedor debe tener una altura definida; si lo que quieres es que ese contenedor tenga también un 100% el padre de éste debe tener altura igualmente, así hasta llegar a la etiqueta `html`, todos los elementos que se vayan anidando hasta llegar al `sidebar` deben tener una altura de 100%:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Otra opción es usar la unidad `vh` que toma la altura de la pantalla:

```
.sidebar{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: La segunda opcion me funciono perfectamente, gracias :)

Answer (score 2):

La solución de @blonfu funciona pefrecto. Pero si tu aplicación es un más dashboard, que es lo que parece, yo te recomiendo hacer dos cosas además de lo que ya te mencionaron:

2. El sidebar y el content debe tener un `height: 100%`.
3. El contenedor no debe ser scrollable. En su lugar, debe serlo el `content`.

Es una manera de mantener una buena UX, porque el usuario, **jamás va a perder de vista las áreas importantes**, como son el menú y la barra superior donde va el menú de usuario (perfil, cerrar sesión, etc.).

Te pongo un ejemplo

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .sidebar {
  background-color: #34495e;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .23s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
}

.container .content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .content .top {
  background-color: #fff;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.container .content .main {
  background-color: #F2F8FA;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#box {
  background-color: coral;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .container .sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 70px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    
  </aside>
  <section class="content">
    <header class="top">
      
    </header>
    <article class="main">
       <div id="box"></div>
    </article>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Queda toda deforme la pagina :p

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ALJHf